# HTML Form get data is UTF8 but post data is not?

Tags: perl, post, utf-8, get, cgi

I have a problem with some perl CGI scripts that have to deal with special german letters.

My problem is that for example an `ö` character that I input into a text field is being read correctly if my form uses GET but if I use POST it becomes `Ã¶`. I need it to work with POST, so switching to GET is not a possibility.

The webserver uses utf8, my script is saved as utf8, I explicitly told perl to treat all CGI input as utf8 with "use CGI -utf8;" and my databases has the client encoding set to utf8.

What may I be missing?

Comment: You're missing some example code. Without it we would all just be guessing.

Comment: Discussing this with the CGI.pm maintainer on IRC and it would be helpful to know which version of CGI.pm you are using.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. Any demonstration at all would be a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this with the [example](https://metacpan.org/source/LEEJO/CGI-4.21/examples/wikipedia_example.cgi) included in the CGI distribution, which uses a simple form to POST data in a text field. The example works in its current state with utf8 data. If the `-utf8` flag to `use CGI` is **included** the ö char will be corrupted. So this is most likely a bug.

Edit: Digging a bit deeper this is because the utf-8 bit is not set on the variable - CGI [tries](https://github.com/leejo/CGI.pm/blob/master/lib/CGI.pm#L448) to DTRT, but if the utf-8 bit is not set then it *will* decode. I'll try to look into this sometime soon, no promises though...